# Android and sim-lock

Tags: sim-card, dual-sim, sim-unlocking

I'd like to know if android phones are sim-locked. Given that they are open-source and have community images it should be 'tricky' to sim-lock one but I prefere to ask.

Also - do I need to unlock if I use dual-sim adapter with one legal card in it?

Answer (score 4):

This differs from carrier to carrier. Some will be sim-locked, some aren't. You'll have to ask your carrier. It has nothing to do with the OS.

Comment: Short of inserting a SIM card from another carrier, how can one tell whether an Android phone is SIM locked?

Comment: @Derek: Call your carrier. But if you got the phone subsidized, it's probably locked. Wikipedia has [some information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIM_lock#Laws_and_Practices_on_SIM.2Fnetwork_locking) about relevant laws.